# Total number of additions and multiplications in the following code?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Really stumped on this question... I think it's n(n+1)? or is it(n+1)^2? Will someone help me? Thank you!!

What is the total number of additions and multiplications in the following code?

```
  s := 0

  for i := 1 to n

      s:= s + i
     for j:= 1 to i
          s := s + j*i
      next j
 next i

 s := s+10
```

Comment: Do you count the implicit additions for incrementing `i` and `j` every iteration? (That is, does `next i` count as an "addition"?)

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that the increments of `i` and `j` do not count as operations.

There are 2 operations (1 addition, 1 multiplication) in the innermost loop.
How many times is the inner-most loop executed? If it helps, see what happens when $n=3$ or something.

> The inner-most loop is executed $1+2+\cdots+n$ times, which is equal to $n(n+1)/2$.

What is left is the `s:=s+i` and `s:=s+10` lines, which I think you can handle.